# Orientdb fetch relationship as array in json

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientjs

I want to fetch the vertices connected by the edge to be returned as an array as a property in json.

Eg: If a POST has 10 comments the query should return something like this.

```
{
    @class: Post,
    postTitle: "Some title",
    comments: [
        { 
           @class: Comment,
           content: "First Comment,
           someKey: "Some Value"  
        },
        { 
           @class: Comment,
           content: "Second Comment
           someKey: "Some Value"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is possible to get one property of the vertices in an array by this query

```
select *, out('HAS_COMMENT').content as comments from POST
```

This will result in an array which has only the value of 'content' property in the Comment class

I need to fetch the full record as a nested json.

### UPDATE

If I just use `out('HAS_COMMENT')` in the query instead of `out('HAS_COMMENT').content` , it returns the `@rid` field instead of full record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your case with this structure :

```
create class Post extends V
create class Comment extends V
create class HAS_COMMENT extends E

create property Post.postTitle String
create property Comment.content String
create property Comment.someKey Integer

create vertex Post set postTitle="First"
create vertex Post set postTitle="Second"
create vertex Comment set content="First Comment", someKey="1"
create vertex Comment set content="Second Comment", someKey="2"
create vertex Comment set content="Third Comment", someKey="3"
create vertex Comment set content="Fourth Comment", someKey="4"
create vertex Comment set content="Fifth Comment", someKey="5"
create vertex Comment set content="Sixth Comment", someKey="6"
create vertex Comment set content="Seventh Comment", someKey="7"
create vertex Comment set content="Eighth Comment", someKey="8"
create vertex Comment set content="Ninth Comment", someKey="9"
create vertex Comment set content="Tenth Comment", someKey="10"
create vertex Comment set content="Eleventh Comment", someKey="11"
create vertex Comment set content="Twelfth Comment", someKey="12"
create vertex Comment set content="Thirteenth Comment", someKey="13"
create vertex Comment set content="Fourteenth Comment", someKey="14"

create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="First Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Second Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Third Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Fourth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Fifth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Sixth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Seventh Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Eighth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Ninth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="First") to (select from Comment where content="Tenth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="Second") to (select from Comment where content="Eleventh Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="Second") to (select from Comment where content="Twelfth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="Second") to (select from Comment where content="Thirteenth Comment")
create edge HAS_COMMENT from (select from Post where postTitle="Second") to (select from Comment where content="Fourteenth Comment")
```

To get the result you want, you can use the following **query**:

```
select expand($ris)
    let $a = (select from Post where postTitle = 'First'),
        $b = (select from Comment where in('HAS_COMMENT').postTitle in $a.postTitle),
        $ris = unionAll($a,$b)
```

**Studio**:

[image]

**Console output**:

```
----+-----+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+--------------
#   |@RID |@CLASS |postTitle|out_HAS_COMMENT|content        |someKey|in_HAS_COMMENT
----+-----+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+--------------
0   |#12:0|Post   |First    |[size=10]      |null           |null   |null
1   |#13:0|Comment|null     |null           |First Comment  |1      |[size=1]
2   |#13:1|Comment|null     |null           |Second Comment |2      |[size=1]
3   |#13:2|Comment|null     |null           |Third Comment  |3      |[size=1]
4   |#13:3|Comment|null     |null           |Fourth Comment |4      |[size=1]
5   |#13:4|Comment|null     |null           |Fifth Comment  |5      |[size=1]
6   |#13:5|Comment|null     |null           |Sixth Comment  |6      |[size=1]
7   |#13:6|Comment|null     |null           |Seventh Comment|7      |[size=1]
8   |#13:7|Comment|null     |null           |Eighth Comment |8      |[size=1]
9   |#13:8|Comment|null     |null           |Ninth Comment  |9      |[size=1]
10  |#13:9|Comment|null     |null           |Tenth Comment  |10     |[size=1]
----+-----+-------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+--------------
```

About your question underlined in your **UPDATE**, to get the full record/s from the `@rid` you can use the `expand()` function.

Example:

Getting all of the comments connected with the vertex Post where `postTitle = 'Second'`

**Query**: `select expand(out('HAS_COMMENT')) from Post where postTitle = 'Second'`

**Studio**:

[image]

**Console output**:

```
----+------+-------+------------------+-------+--------------
#   |@RID  |@CLASS |content           |someKey|in_HAS_COMMENT
----+------+-------+------------------+-------+--------------
0   |#13:10|Comment|Eleventh Comment  |11     |[size=1]
1   |#13:11|Comment|Twelfth Comment   |12     |[size=1]
2   |#13:12|Comment|Thirteenth Comment|13     |[size=1]
3   |#13:13|Comment|Fourteenth Comment|14     |[size=1]
----+------+-------+------------------+-------+--------------
```

Hope it helps

**EDITED**

**Query**:

```
select *, $a as comments from Post
let $a = (select @class, content, someKey from Comment where in('HAS_COMMENT').postTitle in $parent.current.postTitle)
```

**Studio**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.But what I need all these in one query.. I tried expand. It was not giving the intended result. In my question I have shown the expected output. So I need all the records of class Comment to come in a property called 'comments'

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know

Comment: This worked in Studio but when I did this using orient js Its giving the complete json. I have raised an issue in orientjs.. Here is the link https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/issues/139

Comment: Hi, you can also try this: `select *, $a as comments from Post
let $a = (select expand(@this.include('@class','content','someKey')) from Comment where in('HAS_COMMENT').postTitle in $parent.current.postTitle)`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. BTW From where are you finding these queries :) . I googled a lot and I couldn't find much. If there are some blogs or docs available please share it.

Comment: Hi, I found it here [orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Methods.html](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Methods.html) and I think you could find a lot of useful methods. In your case it also could be useful the `.toJSON()` method.